# Display IplImage as Android Bitmap

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, java-native-interface

I'm working on a facedetect Android application which uses the OpenCV
2.3.1 library. I've found some code which allow me to make a photo on
my Samsung GT-P1000 and save it in the gallery. Then I want to select
the image from the gallery which allows a .cpp file to use OpenCV
functions. This requires a bitmap to IplImage conversion (the .java
and .cpp code snippets are added below).

**The java code looks like this:**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentImagePath);
Log.i(TAG, mCurrentImagePath);
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
opencv.setSourceImage(pixels, width, height);
byte[] imageData = opencv.getSourceImage();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
imageData.length);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**The C++ code looks like this:**

```
IplImage * pImage = NULL;
IplImage * loadpixels(int * pixels, int width, int height);
IplImage * getIplImageFromIntArray
    (JNIEnv* env, jintArray array_data, jint width, jint height);

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_org_opencv_example_pruts_Test1OpenCV_setSourceImage
    (JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jintArray photo_data, jint width, jint height)
{
    if(pImage != NULL)
    {
        cvReleaseImage(&pImage);
        pImage = NULL;
    }

    pImage = getIplImageFromIntArray(env, photo_data, width, height);
    if(pImage == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

However I need another JNIEXPORT function which converts the IplImage
to bitmap data. Therefor the last 4 lines of code will be used. imageData should be filled so BitmapFactory can decode it. I came across load of examples and these code snippets come from those as well. However I'm not able to find a solution for my problem. Does anyone has some suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you intend to use compressed format and it's feasible, but complex.
here I give a solution using uncompressed data.
Because Bitmap in android basically is in rgba format, so you can create bitmap using IplImage data directly except the byte alignment problem.

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_org_opencv_example_pruts_Test1OpenCV_getSourceImage
    (JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz){    
    if(pImage == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int len = pImage->width * pImage->height * 4;
    jintArray rgbaData = env->NewIntArray(len);
    if(pImage->nChannels == 4){
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(rgbaData,0,len,(jint*)pImage->imageData);
    }else if(pImage->nChannels == 3){
        IplImage* t = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(pImage),8,4);
        for(int h = 0; h< pImage->height; h++){
            char* pt= t->imageData + h * t->widthStep;
            char* pImg = pImage->imageData+ h * pImage->widthStep;
            for(int w =0 ; w < pImage->width; w++){
                memcpy(pt,pImg,3);
                pt[3] = 255;//alpha 
                pt+=4;
                pImg += 3;
            }
        }
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(rgbaData,0,len,(jint*)t->imageData);
        cvReleaseImage(&t);
    }else {
        // if pImage -> nChannels == 1 , handle it in the way you prefer 
        // I donot think your image is gray ,so forget about this situation
    }

    cvReleaseImage(&pImage);
    return rgbaData;
}
```

And the java code should be like this:

```
int[] imageData = opencv.getSourceImage();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageData, 0, width,width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
```